# Should one scale the predictors for option pricing?

Tags: neural-networks, dataset, scales, feature-scaling

I am not sure to know when one should scale the data used for feeding a NN.

I am fitting an NN to the B&S formula. I compute the option pricing for different parameters value (strike price, asset's price...).

**And I don't know if I should scale my data.**

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should normalize your input using some method. This happens for at least two reasons:

1) Inputs of different magnitudes will affect differently the weights of the neural network. This will make the convergence more difficulty.

2) If the input are larger it can cause the saturation of the intermediate units of the neural network.

Comment: That I know, it is for that reason that I am asking. However, I don't know if it's common practice to do that for option pricing, and if perhaps certain parameters should be kept the same.

Comment: What parameters are you talking about? Exactly?

Comment: sorry I don't do enough statistics to have my vocabulary exactly accurate. I meant the features / predictors. The one I am talking about here are : "strike price, maturity, interest rate, initial asset value, vol of vol..."

Comment: I think you not have any problem if you normalize (scale) these features (predictors). Look: the order of magniture of the strike prices and interest rates may be completelly different. Imagine the effect (bad one) that will happen if you do not normalize your features!

Comment: OK thanks for the advice Daniel ! If you don't mind, I ll leave the question option, perhaps someone has another point of view on the question.